# ruby regular expression to remove the last occurrence

Tags: ruby

how to use a ruby regular expression to remove left to right with the last /

example: **C:/Users/sino/Documents/window/testing.mp4**

the result: **testing.txt**

thank you for helping me

Comment: A regular expression itself can not **remove** anything; it can **match** certain part of the string, and you can get information about the matched parts. BTW, when you want `testing.txt` as a result, where does the `.txt` come from? The full path has `.mp4` at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `File.basename`

```
 File.basename("C:/Users/sino/Documents/window/testing.mp4")
```

If you still want the regular expression, then

```
a="C:/Users/sino/Documents/window/testing.mp4"

p a.gsub(/.*\//,"")
```

Output

```
 testing.mp4
```

Comment: Great! Which one did you use? RegEx or  File.basename?

Answer (score 1):

Though I prefer the use of `File.basename`, as suggested by @Rajagopalen, here are two more ways to obtain the desired result.

```
str1 = "C:/Users/sino/Documents/window/testing.mp4"
str2 = "testing.mp4"
```

---

```
R = /
    [^\/]+  # match one or more characters other than a forward slash 
    \z      # match end of string
    /x      # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

or, equivalently,

```
R = /[^\/]+\z/
```

```
str1[R]
  #=> "testing.mp4"
str2[R]
  #=> "testing.mp4"
```

---

```
(idx = str1.rindex('/')) ? str1[idx+1..-1] : str1
  #=> "testing.mp4"
(idx = str2.rindex('/')) ? str2[idx+1..-1] : str2
  #=> "testing.mp4"
```

See [String#rindex](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/String.html#method-i-rindex).